# Cached Property: Easier way?

Tags: c#, caching, properties

I have a object with properties that are expensive to compute, so they are only calculated on first access and then cached.

```
 private List<Note> notes;
 public List<Note> Notes
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.notes == null)
            {
                this.notes = CalcNotes();
            }
            return this.notes;
        }
    }
```

I wonder, is there a better way to do this? Is it somehow possible to create a Cached Property or something like that in C#?

Comment: The only thing I'd watch out for here is that while the property may seem to be read-only, a List<> is a mutable object, and thus whomever gets the reference can alter it.  They can't null out the private member, but they can make the List<> empty.  I'd return an IEnumerable<> or something instead if you can get away with it.  But that's not your direct question.  What Oded said seems OK to me.

Comment: @Kevin: `ReadOnlyCollection<Note>` is a good choice here as well (arguably better since it offers indexing and the entire array is available).

Comment: In additional to the original post, in terms of 'separation of concerns' it would be nice to be able to have a class that just returns the data as normal, and then a child class that deals with caching the data. Other than doing it manually, there doesn't seem to be a pretty way of achieving this. Anybody?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As far as syntax goes, you can use the [null-coalescing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator if you want to be fancy, but it's not necessarily as readable.

```
get
{
    return notes ?? (notes = CalcNotes());
}
```

**Edit: Updated courtesy of Matthew. Also, I think the other answers are more helpful to the question asker!**

Comment: `return notes ?? (notes = CalcNotes());` would be slightly more efficient.

Comment: Sorry I messed up the second `??`... I corrected it to `=`.  This version will only do the secondary assignment if the value is null.  Your version will always reassign the value.

Comment: @Matthew that is exactly how I handle any lazy properties as of current day.

Comment: Looks really cool! Will definitely be using this syntax for <=3.5.Net

Comment: In C# 6.0 it can be reduced even to one-liner `List<Note> Notes => notes ?? (notes = CalcNotes());`

Comment: and what about ??= operator? `notes ??= CalcNotes()`

Comment: And if `null` is not an option, one could simply use the ternary operator `return notes == unsetValue ? (notes = CalcNotes()) : notes;`

Answer (score 23):

In .NET 3.5 or earlier, what you have is a very standard practice, and a fine model.

(Although, I would suggest returning `IList<T>`, or `IEnumerable<T>` if possible, instead of `List<T>` in your public API - `List<T>` should be an implementation detail...)

In .NET 4, however, there is a simpler option here: [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(VS.100).aspx).  This lets you do:

```
private Lazy<IList<Note>> notes;
public IEnumerable<Note> Notes
{
    get
    {
        return this.notes.Value;
    }
}

// In constructor:
this.notes = new Lazy<IList<Note>>(this.CalcNotes);
```

Comment: Looks interesting, too bad you still need a backing variable. The amount of code is even more spread throughout the class, and it's not really less code to write, so no real benefits I would say. There should be a Lazy Property construction way, just like {get; private set;} but then with a reference to the calculation method that needs to be called.

Comment: Peterdk: THat's basically what `Lazy<T>` gives you.. it's tough to do "lazy construction" via a func<T> without having a separate way to define the construction function.  It's quite a bit simpler without that (since you can just use "private Lazy<List<Note>> note = new Lazy<List<Note>>();" (no constructor issues)...  This, however, does have the MAJOR advantage of being completely thread safe, where your original is not...

Comment: Reed: Ok, nice to know. Will look a bit more into the Lazy thing. Can't find out yet if it's supported on WP7, for now I'll use the null-coalescing operating suggested by frou. This is however definitely the way to go in future .Net versions.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with `??` is that if `CalcNotes()` returns `null` then it will not be cached any more. Ditto for value types if for example both `0` and `NaN` are allowed as property value.

Much better would be an "aspect-oriented" solution, something like [Post](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp)-[Sharp](http://doc.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/2.0/##PostSharp.chm/html/d3631074-e131-467e-947b-d99f348eb40d.htm) does using attributes and then modifying MSIL (bytecode).

The code would look like:

```
[Cached]
public List<Note> Notes { get { return CalcNotes(); } }
```

**EDIT:** [CciSharp.LazyProperty.dll](http://ccisamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=LazyProperty&referringTitle=CciSharp) does exactly this!!!

Comment: Do not patch the authentic code what the compiler emitted. Period.

Answer (score 5):

A two-line option with C# 8 and [null-coalescing assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator):

```
private List<Note>? notes;
public List<Note> Notes => notes ??= CalcNotes();
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks pretty standard to me. What you are doing is fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** it is possible. The question is, how much you are winning by doing it - you still need the initialization code somewhere, so at most you will be saving the conditional expression.

A while ago I implemented a class to handle this. You can find the code posted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440290/implementing-a-lazyproperty-class-is-this-a-good-idea), where I ask whether it's a good idea. There are some interesting opinions in the answers, be sure to read them all before deciding to use it.

## Edit:

A [Lazy<T> class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(VS.100).aspx) that does basically the same as my implementation that I link to above, has been added to the .NET 4 Framework; so you can use that if you are on .NET 4. See an example here: http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/05/19/net-framework-4-0-using-system-lazy-lt-t-gt.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If the value is non-trivial to compute, I generally prefer using a method (`GetNotes()`). There's nothing stopping you from caching the value with a method, plus you can add the [`[Pure]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.pureattribute(VS.100).aspx) attribute (.NET 4) if applicable to indicate the method does not alter the state of the object.

If you do decide to stay with the following, I recommend:

Whenever you have a lazily-evaluated property, you should add the following attribute to ensure that running in the debugger behaves the same as running outside of it:

```
[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
```

Also, starting with .NET 4, you can use the following:

```
// the actual assignment will go in the constructor.
private readonly Lazy<List<Note>> _notes = new Lazy<List<Note>>(CalcNotes);

[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
public List<Note> Notes
{
    get { return _notes.Value; }
}
```

Comment: Unless CalcNotes is static, this won't compile, since the inline construction requires a static context - you'll need to move the construction into the constructor...

Comment: @Reed Copsey: See the comment...?

Comment: Ahh, okay - missed that ;)  Misleading to have it defined inline, IMO.